# Prediction IO: build, no engine found

Tags: predictionio

After following the quickstart (for 0.11.1 build) on https://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/templates/recommendation/quickstart/ I'm failing to build the template/engine (I've tried to build both MyRecommendation and another NLP template). `pio build --verbose` ends with :

```
[INFO] [Engine$] Compilation finished successfully.
[INFO] [Engine$] Looking for an engine...
[ERROR] [Engine$] No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting.
```

When I try to run `pio train` it fails with :

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: object org.example.recommendation.RecommendationEngine not found.
```

The listener is running ok (data can be also pulled via curl), `pio status` :

```
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting PredictionIO...
[INFO] [Management$] PredictionIO 0.11.1-SNAPSHOT is installed at /home/us/proj/incubator-predictionio/PredictionIO-0.11.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting Apache Spark...
[INFO] [Management$] Apache Spark is installed at /home/us/proj/incubator-predictionio/PredictionIO-0.11.1-SNAPSHOT/vendors/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6
[INFO] [Management$] Apache Spark 2.1.1 detected (meets minimum requirement of 1.3.0)
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting storage backend connections...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Meta Data Backend (Source: PGSQL)...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Model Data Backend (Source: PGSQL)...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Event Data Backend (Source: PGSQL)...
[INFO] [Storage$] Test writing to Event Store (App Id 0)...
[INFO] [Management$] Your system is all ready to go.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Specify your scala version in your build.sbt example

> scalaVersion := "2.11.8"